# Automation pulling data from multiple Data Extensions runs but nothing happens

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I have an automation that pulls data from multiple Data Extensions, (one at a time) since the target Data Extension is the same.

```
Select
Email, 
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CAST([Email] as varchar(350))),
2) AS CustomerKey, 
'xxxxx' AS OptInDetails,
OptinDate,
FirstName, 
LastName, 
Country, 
State,
Permission
From
xxxxx
WHERE xxxxx.email not in (SELECT email from Subscribers)
```

This thing simply won't work...

My solution so far is creating a chain of queries first pulling into Data Extension "new subscribers", then into "subscribers_x" from "new subscribers" and then from "subscribers_x into "Subscribers" this works. Same logic for all queries as mentioned above but different targets.

Does anybody know why I can't write to the master but have to create the "chain"?

Comment: Hi, Martin,
have you tried using SQL joins? This would help you avoid building "chains" and allow to get data from multiple data extensions in a single query (even if the target data extension is the same). Refer to this link for more information: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Hi Rafal, I have though about it, the "issue" with that is that I want the setup to be as "user friendly" for the client as possible, (read, easy SQL). I will try and join them instead and see if that helps, but it still doesn't quite explain why the one thing works over the other:)

Comment: Hi Martin, I had a similar issue a while ago that might be worth taking a look at. "NOT IN" subqueries seem to be rewritten by SFMC, so you get some pretty weird results. Swapping out to a "NOT EXISTS" subquery fixed the issue and the SQL performed just as you'd expect in SQL Query Analyser running your query directly against SQL Server with no parsing and rewrites being done by SFMC. Long shot.

Comment: Hi @Macca, allright, I'll try that! its woth a shot!:) thanks!

Comment: well.. it seems like either the join or not exists wont work as intended. In regards to the join, could it be that subscriberkey is key in the "master" and the data in the "child" aren't given a key before moved to "master"?